# problems in sending and receiving emails by contact form 7 in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

> I have been using contact form 7 to send and receive emails in word-press, every thing was working fine. but suddenly it stopped working at all.
>   problem statement is as bellow

1. i am using gmail services to send and receive emails for example
   **info@mydomain.com**
2. contact form 7 (in word press) plugin is being used for sending and receiving emails on website that i am working on.
3. suddenly hosting server(big rock) closes the port 80 as it reported spamming from  website due to virus infection in files.
4. c panel virus scanner showed every thing clean after replacing the infected files and port 80 got opened once again. but still unable to send and receive emails, however it displays success message after submitting the form
5. i also created an email id using c panel , and then used it in **To** and **From** field in contact-form-7 settings but it didnt work at all
6. one more thing, i could send an email by this newly created id using web mail. on the other end , on other account in gmail i received it but when i replied it back , i got failure message like `Google tried to deliver your message, but it was rejected by the server for the recipient domain mydomain.com by aspmx.l.google.com. [2607:f8b0:4003:c0e::1b].`

> please help me in this regard

Comment: Please first contact to server provider for that. As you mention _suddenly hosting server(big rock) closes the port 80 as it reported spamming from website due to virus infection in files_

Comment: i did every thing but still helpless, big rock changed three files   `authmail.php`
`class.smtp.php`
`class.phpmailer.php`  in public html folder. however i wish to know do i need to be worried about phpmailer file if i am using contact form 7 plugins in wordpress

Comment: You can setup [WP Mail Bank](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-mail-bank/) plugin if you are using SMTP complex setup. This plugin reconfigures the `wp_mail()` function nd make it more enhanced to use SMTP instead of` mail()` with various options available.

Comment: i used `wp smtp` instead. the test email was sent successfully but the recipient could not reply to the email id (created in my domain using c panel) and still contact form 7 is unable to send emails however it shows success message

Comment: What if you send mail using other tool(viz. thunderbird OR else) from your domain?

Comment: see , i am also using out look express for sending/receiving emails further , all the email ids for instance emailid@mydomainName.com  (all ids hosted by gmail server) are still able to send/receive emails from outlook or gmail.  the problem is contact-form-7 is not able to send emails

Comment: So the issue only with _contact form 7 (in word press) plugin_. Right?

Comment: it seems so, however i updated that too. but went useless (pls note mydomain emails id are hosted by gmail server not by the big rock)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100941/discussion-between-addweb-solution-pvt-ltd-and-dilver-singh).

Answer (score 0):

Mention your domain email in from setting in contact form 7. Try this.